# Is it better to use mvn post-clean install than mvn clean install?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have seen my colleagues use

```
$ mvn clean install
```

Is it more 'correct' to use

```
$ mvn post-clean install
```

so we are also executing the post-clean phase of the clean lifecycle everytime we are 'cleaning'.

Comment: How do you define "more correct"?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469611/maven-pre-and-post-phases

Answer (score 3):

If you look up "Built-in Lifecycle Bindings" in [Introduction to the Lifecylce](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) you see that the `post-clean` phase is empty in the standard configuration. So calling `clean` and `post-clean` will do exactly the same unless you explicitly bind something to `post-clean`.

Furthermore the same document discourages to call `post-*` and `pre-*` phases ("Some Phases Are Not Usually Called From the Command Line")