# Maven `pre` and `post` phases

Tags: maven

Are the `pre` and `post` phases always executed when I execute the associated phase? For example, if I do `mvn clean`, will this execute the `mvn post-clean` phase, too?

I was looking at https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference, in which it said:

> The following lists all build phases of the default, clean and site
>   lifecycles, which are executed in the order given **up to the point of
>   the one specified.**

So strictly speaking, since `post-clean` comes after `clean`, it should not be executed if I just do `mvn clean`. But my gut feel is different - although, I didn't find a way to verify this, as the maven stdout doesn't print the phase it's executing.

Could anyone weigh in on the answer and how you verified?

Comment: The clean life cycle consists of three phases `pre-clean`, `clean` and `post-clean` and if you call `mvn clean` the phase `post-clean` will not being executed. You can simply bind a plugin to the `post-clean` (echo plugin? etc.) and see if it will be executed by calling `mvn clean`....

Comment: Have a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5668 . This might be improved in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind a plugin (such as [`echo-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/Ekryd/echo-maven-plugin)) to the phases of the `clean` lifecycle to help verify if/when each phase is executed.

For example, given the following plugin definition:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.ekryd.echo-maven-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>echo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-clean</id>
            <phase>pre-clean</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>echo</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <message>In 'pre-clean'</message>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>echo</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <message>In 'clean'</message>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-clean</id>
            <phase>post-clean</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>echo</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <message>In 'post-clean'</message>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Invoking `mvn clean` will result in the following output:

```
$ mvn clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- echo-maven-plugin:1.2.0:echo (pre-clean) @ sandbox ---
[INFO] In 'pre-clean'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ sandbox ---
[INFO] Deleting target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- echo-maven-plugin:1.2.0:echo (clean) @ sandbox ---
[INFO] In 'clean'
```

So, there's no invocation of the `post-clean` phase there.

Invoking `mvn clean compile` will result in the following output:

```
$ mvn clean compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- echo-maven-plugin:1.2.0:echo (pre-clean) @ sandbox ---
[INFO] In 'pre-clean'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ sandbox ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- echo-maven-plugin:1.2.0:echo (clean) @ sandbox ---
[INFO] In 'clean'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ sandbox ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ sandbox ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to ...
```

Again, there's no invocation of the `post-clean` phase there. This implies that the maven-clean-plugin (and perhaps nothing else) is not bound to `post-clean`.

Invoking `mvn post-clean` *will* result in the `post-clean` phase being invoked ...

```
$ mvn post-clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- echo-maven-plugin:1.2.0:echo (pre-clean) @ sandbox ---
[INFO] In 'pre-clean'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ sandbox ---
[INFO] Deleting target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- echo-maven-plugin:1.2.0:echo (clean) @ sandbox ---
[INFO] In 'clean'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- echo-maven-plugin:1.2.0:echo (post-clean) @ sandbox ---
[INFO] In 'post-clean'
```

So, based on the above test I think the following statements are true:

- `post-clean` is **not** invoked when you call `clean`
- `post-clean` is **only** called when you explicitly invoke `post-clean` (note: invoking the `pre-` and `post-` phases directly is unusual)

Comment: I don't understand why the 'post-clean' phase isn't invoked when you run `mvn clean compile`.  After all, you have set up an execution for the echo-maven-plugin in that phase. Why are some phases invoked and others not?

Comment: @gjoranv: by default, `maven-clean-plugin` is not bound to the `post-clean` phase. Unlike some other plugins - such as failsafe - which actually have something to do in a `post-` phase there isn't really anything to do *after* cleaning so perhaps the authors of `maven-clean-plugin` decided that there was no point in binding to `post-clean`.

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear. I'm wondering why the `post-clean` phase is not invoked when you have specified an execution for the echo-maven-plugin in that phase. Is it something special with the echo-maven-plugin, or must one in general verify that some other plugin is bound to the phase you want your `execution` to be invoked in?

Comment: The only time I "specified an execution for the echo-maven-plugin in that phase" was when I invoked `mvn post-clean` (i.e. in the third example above) and on that occasion `post-clean` **was** invoked. This is not a peculiarity of the `echo-maven-plugin`, it simply reflects the fact that nothing invokes `post-clean` by default and instead - if we want that phase to be invoked - we must invoke it explicitly.